# can't sum my list because of commas

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list of numbers input by the user. The list is of random length depending on how many elements the user inputs. 
python sees the list (e.g) like this:
the numbers you entered are:

```
['6', '7', '8', '4', '5', '98', '34', '56']
```

They are on a list called `numlist`.

I want to sum the list - so I tried

```
print(sum (numlist)
```

It won't sum, i reckon, because of the commas. which I believe makes them string items not list. so, i think i have to remove the commas, thus turning them into a list, which i can sum.
I've looked all over, i can't find a solution that makes sense to me. (sorry I'm quite new to this. )

I've experimented with strip. map. and int. but I can't find one that will do the job. obviously I'm setting up the code incorrectly someplace. Please help.

Comment: Instead of describing, can you share your actual code? It would be easier to pinpoint the error that way.

Comment: Show the code instead of text

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add up string elements of list. If you want sum of list elements. For e.g. if you have a list

```
a = ['1','2']
```

1) Convert list elements of `a` to `int` and assign to  list `b`

```
 b= [int(i) for i in a ]
```

2) Sum the list elements using `sum`

```
 print sum(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're trying to add together a list of strings, you have to convert those strings to integers first before calling `sum`; try doing this:

```py
print(sum(int(item) for item in numlist))
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just fyi, you're normally expected to accept an answer if the solution worked out

Answer (score 0):

```
numlist =[1,2,3,4,5]
sum=0
for element in numlist:
    sum+=element
print sum
```

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes indeed make your list a list of strings.  You need to turn the strings into numbers. For completeness sake:

```
sum(map(int, numlist))
sum(map(float, numlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the easiest and most efficient:

```
print(sum(map(int, numlist)))
```